# Azure B2C custom domain has been previously configured using an existing Azure AD or Office 365

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I am planning to move some of my applications from AzureAD authentication to Azure B2C.  I have an existing Azure AD Tenant that has a custom domain assigned and verified and I use this for all of my internal Office 365 and AzureAD authenticated applications.  I do not want to change any of this as it is working well.

I then created an Azure B2C tenant using the instructions provided here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-create-tenant.  That also worked and I have been able to register applications and create sample Flows.

However, I now want to assign a custom domain to the Azure B2C tenant and I would like to use the same domain that I am using for my existing applications in the AzureAD tenant.  I use subdomains on my web server to separate the various applications.

I used the instructions here to create the custom domain in my Azure B2C tenant and add the TXT record to my domain registrar.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-domain?pivots=b2c-user-flow.

However, when I try to verify my domain, I get a message stating that

> This domain has been previously configured on
> [Azure Domain Prefix].onmicrosoft.com using an existing Azure AD or Office 365.
> To verify this domain name, you will first need to remove the domain
> name from the existing directory.

[image]

I tried adding the subdomain to the Azure B2C tenant, but understandably this "domain" was not able to be found in the verification step.

Does anyone know how I can get around this?  My understanding is that I can't add the B2C functionality to an existing AzureAD tenant and I really don't want to move everything from my existing AzureAD tenant, nor create a new domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have now worked out why I had this problem and will post an answer to help anyone else.

The issue was that I was trying to add my top-level domain to the Azure B2C instance.  However, if I followed the instructions more closely, I would have seen that I should be registering **login**.[my-doimain].com.au.  I found the following graphic from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-domain?pivots=b2c-user-flow useful to understand B2C a bit better.

[image]

Comment: Great this worked. Typical of microsoft things not working as they seem and documentation scattered everywhere.